# can i disable autorotation while writing file to path?

Tags: iphone, ipad, process, autorotate

in my app i have a process to writting a file from UITextView. When the process on going, i want to display some alert so user can not do anything when the process is not finished. The problem is when the saving process happen and then i rotate the device or the simulator, some background process is disturbed, so it crash my app.

I think maybe i have to disable the autorotation, when this saving process happen. But I dont know what to do. is my idea right??? Can somebody help me to do this??

**UPDATE**

this is my snippet code to try solving this problem

```
  -(void)showAlertIndicator{


    alertSave = [[CustomAlertIndicator alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomAlertIndicator" bundle:nil];

    isSavingFile = YES;
    [alertSave show];

    [textView.text writeToFile:newFilePath atomically :YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error :nil];

    [self dismissAlertIndicator];
}

    -(void)dismissAlertIndicator{

    [alertSave dismiss];
    isSavingFile = NO;
}



 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {   
    if (isSavingFile == YES) {
        return NO;
    }else {
        return YES;
    }

}
```

but it still not works.

Thank you

Regards,

Risma

Answer (score 0):

check for this and make you BOOL FALSE when it is true

if([textView.text writeToFile:newFilePath atomically :YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error :nil])

{

```
 isSavingFile = NO:
```

}

Comment: thank you for your answer, i was try this, but it's not work too

Comment: Its working at my end but i think main problem is that this bool becomes no before you rotate your device so check using break points in should auto rotate function.